# Использование функции Lookup для DataFrame с двустрочным заголовком

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, multi-index

У меня есть 2 таблицы (DataFrame). Первая с двустрочным заголовком:

```
 lvl0    ID   2020     2021     
 lvl1         1  2  3  1  2  3
         A    1  0  3  2  1  1
         B    5  4  7  6  2  2
         C    9  8 11 10  3  3
         D   13 12 15 14  4  4
         E   17 16 19 18  5  5
```

Где первая строка в таблице означает собой год, а вторая строка - вариант реализации (1,2,3), и далее в таблице для каждого Id предусмотрены свои значения.

И вторая таблица:

```
        ID   Var          
         A    1  
         B    1  
         C    1 
         D    2 
         E    1
         F    2
         G    3
```

Задача во вторую таблицу для каждого ID добавить значения по условию из варианта реализации `Var`. То есть, я пытаюсь сделать `Lookup` значения во вторую таблицу, если оно удовлетворяет критерию `var`. Значение должно браться из соответсвующей варианту реализации колонки в таблицы 1, но так необходимо сделать для каждого года. Должно быть так:

```
            ID   Var   2020  2021       
             A    1     1      1
             B    1     5      2
             C    1     9      6
             D    2    12      4
             E    1    17     18
```

Для обычной таблицы (DataFrame) с одной строкой заголовка отлично работает следующий вариант:

```
df2[2020] = df1.set_index('ID').lookup(df2['ID'], df2['Var'])
```

А вот как сделать для сложного заголовка, не пойму. Годов будет много до 2040, как и вариантов ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = \
(df
 .set_index("ID")
 .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
 .apply(lambda x: 
            pd.Series(x.droplevel(0, axis=1).lookup(df2["ID"], df2["Var"]),
                      name=x.columns.get_level_values(0)[0])))
res.insert(0, "ID", df["ID"])
res.insert(1, "Var", df2["Var"])
```

---

результат:

```
In [97]: res
Out[97]:
  ID  Var  2020  2021
0  A    1     1     2
1  B    1     5     6
2  C    1     9    10
3  D    2    12     4
4  E    1    17    18
```

---

исходные фреймы:

```
In [98]: df
Out[98]:
  ID 2020         2021
        1   2   3    1  2  3
0  A    1   0   3    2  1  1
1  B    5   4   7    6  2  2
2  C    9   8  11   10  3  3
3  D   13  12  15   14  4  4
4  E   17  16  19   18  5  5

In [99]: df2
Out[99]:
  ID  Var
0  A    1
1  B    1
2  C    1
3  D    2
4  E    1
```

Comment: Спасибо! В таком варианте это работает, но когда я пытаюсь считать таблицу из Excel у меня появляется пустая строка и в датафрейме она оформляется как Unnamed: 1_level_1 в колонке ID. А далее при попытке сделать set_index - происходит ошибка "ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional". Как в этом случае прафильно оформить таблицу эксель, или какие параметры надо установить при считывании файла?

Comment: @Илья, можете привести пример данных, который поможет воспроизвести ошибку? Я думаю лучше задать новый SO вопрос о том как считывать Excel файл так, чтобы получить multi-index заголовки в Pandas DataFrame...

Comment: вопрос задал тут: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134619/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-excel-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-pandas-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-multiindex)