# Считывание Excel файлов для получения MultiIndex заголовков

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, multi-index

Задача - правильно считать файл Excel, который содержит таблицу с многострочным заголовком. Пример [используемых данных](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K2P87FwDjZqZhSLYxtd7jZ3_fNDHvMNI/view?usp=sharing).

Для считывания использую следующий подход:

```
param = pd.read_excel('parameters.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col = 0)
```

В результате получается следующая структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - как считать таблицу или организовать ее в Excel правильно для того, чтобы можно было использовать MultiIndex?

В частности, сделать колонку `Asset` индексом для `lookup` функции, а `Unnamed:1_level_1` убрать.

Comment: @MaxU должен быть доступ. Открыл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\download\parameters.xlsx", header=[0,1], index_col=0)
df = df.rename(columns=lambda col: "" if str(col).startswith("Unnamed:") else col, level=1)
```

---

результат:

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]:
   Asset      2020                       2021
                 1       2         3        1       2        3
0      1  101.0800  106.40  111.7200  105.925  111.50  117.075
1     23   82.5075   86.85   91.1925   78.394   82.52   86.646
2     25   42.9400   45.20   47.4600   41.154   43.32   45.486
3     30    0.0000    0.00    0.0000    0.000    0.00    0.000
4     32    0.0000    0.00    0.0000    0.000    0.00    0.000
..   ...       ...     ...       ...      ...     ...      ...
35    42    0.0000    0.00    0.0000    0.000    0.00    0.000
36    34    0.0000    0.00    0.0000    0.000    0.00    0.000
37    37    0.0000    0.00    0.0000    0.000    0.00    0.000
38    10    2.8400    2.84    2.8400    2.190    2.19    2.190
39     8    0.3700    0.37    0.3700    0.340    0.34    0.340

[40 rows x 7 columns]

In [152]: df.columns
Out[152]:
MultiIndex([('Asset', ''),
            (   2020,  1),
            (   2020,  2),
            (   2020,  3),
            (   2021,  1),
            (   2021,  2),
            (   2021,  3)],
           )
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Илья, пожалуйста! :)